# how to display a products brochures into slides in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, slideshow

I want to add product brochure into slides like [this](https://www.freedom.com.au/shop-catalogue/new-catalogues#view=catalogue&saleId=18149&areaName=Other-states&page=2), anyone please tell me that how can we add these type of slides, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for this, i think adobe may have one with their creative suite if you have that.

That particular example seems to be https://salefinder.com.au am not sure how much that costs however.

Youblisher is free also with a fancy flipping effect. 
http://www.youblisher.com/

There is also Flipgorrilla which is free for a certain number of pages. http://blog.flipgorilla.com/

Flowpaper seems to come up when googling but have never used this.
https://flowpaper.com/

Iframes can be used to embed these if the sites do not have embed codes but just add embed codes or iframes into your CMS to include your PDF catalogues on your store.

This is a more general question however not related to magento and similar questions have been asked here with code examples on how to do this without external sites:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html